# Finding multivariate clusters with survey data (in R)

Tags: r, clustering, categorical-data, survey, standard-error

I'd like to conduct a multivariate cluster analysis on data from the American Community Survey's PUMS microsample (individual level records). I've only performed cluster analysis before when there are no errors (or imagined to be no errors) in the data.

Has anyone tried to combine Thomas Lumley's excellent survey analysis package for R with any of the cluster analysis packages? `Pvclust`, for instance, provides p-values to identify statistically significant clusters. However, I do not know how to feed the standard errors from the survey package into a search for multivariate clusters.  The problem is compounded by the presence of categorical variables relevant to my research.

Comment: Hopefully this partially answers my own question: can I calculate the clusters first and then use the weights and replicate weights to determine how many people were assigned to each cluster?

Comment: i don't understand why it's important to say that your clusters are statistically significant?  it's more of an exploratory tool, no?  if i were you, i'd find a clustering method that will work okay with the main weight.  also: unless you have a massive computer, working with the acs microdata with R's survey package means [you need this](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/american%20community%20survey%20%28acs%29)

Comment: Anthony, you've answered my questions on two different websites now. Thank you!